# Zipping lists together in Common Lisp - Problem with "and"

Tags: list, function, macros, common-lisp

What I am trying to do is create a function `zip` (note now that this is not homework) that iterates through multiple lists simultaneously, applying a function to each list of elements, like so:

```
(zip f '(1 2 3) '(4 5 6) '(7 8 9)) = (list (f 1 4 7) (f 2 5 8) (f 3 6 9))
(zip f '(1 2 3 4) '(5 6) '(7 8 9)) = (list (f 1 5 7) (f 2 6 8))
```

Basically, it stops when any list runs out of elements. Here is my current attempt:

```
(defun zip (f &rest lists)
  (if (apply and lists) ; <- Here is where I think the problem is.
    (cons (apply f (mapcar #'car lists)) (zip f &rest (mapcar #'cdr lists)))
    nil))
```

I would like to know how fix the conditional statement to work with `and`, or something to that effect. I think the problem arises from `and` being a macro. I would also like to know if there is a built-in function for doing this already.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You are re-implementing `mapcar`

```
? (mapcar #'list '(1 2 3) '(4 5 6) '(7 8 9))
((1 4 7) (2 5 8) (3 6 9))
? (mapcar #'list '(1 2 3 4) '(5 6) '(7 8 9))
((1 5 7) (2 6 8))
? (mapcar #'+ '(1 2 3) '(4 5 6) '(7 8 9))
(12 15 18)
? (mapcar #'+ '(1 2 3 4) '(5 6) '(7 8 9))
(13 16)
```

BTW, the function you want in your code in place of `all` is `and`

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know `mapcar` could do that!

Comment: The `all` was accidental. Now what can I do to fix the condition?

Comment: (apply #'and lists)
; and remove the &rest from the 2nd arg to cons

Comment: @Doug Currie: `and` is not a function according to clisp. Also, I now realize that the second argument to `cons` should be (apply zip f (mapcar #'cdr lists)). I need the new lists to be passed as individual arguments.

Comment: There are a few options: (notany #'endp lists) or (every #'identity lists) spring to mind.

Comment: Thanks Refactor and Xach... I should have tried using #'and instead of shooting from the hip. Xach's solutions look good to me.

Comment: See also `pairlis`