# For with multiple in

Tags: objective-c, for-loop

I want to use the basic Objective C stament `for (id object in collection)` with multiple objects and conditions like this:

```
for (Origin *origin in [self.fetchedOriginController fetchedObjects] AND Destiny *destiny in [self.fetchedDestinyController fetchedObjects]))
{
 NSLog(@"This route starts from %@ and ends in %@, origin.name, destiny.name);    
}
```

So the log would be:

```
This route starts in London and ends in Sidney
This route starts in Madrid and ends in Barcelona
This route starts in Washington and ends in Vienna
(...)
```

How can this be done?

Comment: What exactly would be the desired behavior of that loop? Looping though both collections at once? What would be the behavior if one of the collections runs out?

Comment: This is well-established behavior in other languages, @JoachimIsaksson (and damned handy sometimes); Lisp has [`mapcar`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6195809/), Python and Ruby have [`zip()`](https://bradmontgomery.net/blog/2013/04/01/pythons-zip-map-and-lambda/). The iteration stops when one of the lists runs out. I've seen at least two third-party implementations of "zipping" for Cocoa, IIRC.

Comment: @JoshCaswell As I see it, it could at least be a zip, zip_longest or cross join, that's why I asked for clarification.

Comment: Oh, I see; I read your comment as rejecting the idea entirely rather than asking for more specifics, @Joachim.

Comment: Don't ask the same question twice, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for all combinations just nest:

```
for (object in collection)
{
   for (object2 in collection2)
   {
      ...
   }
}
```

Or are you looking for pairs of objects from two same sized collections? If so create a loop which provides the index:

```
NSUInteger count = collection.count;
for (NSUInteger ix = 0; ix < count; ix++)
{
   id object = collection[ix];
   id object2 = collection2[ix];

   ...
}
```

If you want to loop over the common pairs of two different sized collections just change the first line to:

```
NSUInteger count = MIN(collection.count, collection2.count);
```

If you want something else edit your question to be more explicit.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would work for what you're trying I think:

```
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < collection1.count; i++) {

    id object1 = collection1[i];
    id object2 = collection2[i];
    // continue ...

}
```

As far as I know, there's no built in syntax to do what you're asking.

This solution makes the assumption that `collection1` and `collection2` have the same amount of objects, or at least `collection2` doesn't exceed `collection1` in count.  Given your desired syntax, I think you have already planned for this, I just wanted to mention it in case someone else stumbles on this.

Comment: Ideally `i` should be `NSUInteger`, not `int`.

Answer (score 0):

What order do you expect this enumeration to happen in? What kind of association between objects from each collection are you looking for?

If you want to take each `object` from `collection` and do something with both that object and each `object2` in `collection2`, use nested loops:

```
for (object in collection) {
    for (object2 in collection2) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

If you want to go through both collections in order, use two loops.

```
for (object in collection) { /* ... */ }
for (object2 in collection2) { /* ... */ }
```

If you expect some sort of mapping between the objects in `collection` and `collection2` (which presumes they have the same `count` and at least one of them has unique entries), you might look into a data structure that captures that mapping. Then you can iterate across pairs.

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:collection2 forKeys:collection];
[dictionary enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop){
    // ...
}];
```